# How to link_to just by ID number in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to link to a specific database item by just the id number itself, instead of doing something like this:

```
<%= link_to locations_path(@location) do %>
  <li class="border-top border-bottom">Location</li>
<% end %>
```

I would like to link by the id number manually, something
like this:

```
<%= link_to locations_path(82) do %>
  <li class="border-top border-bottom">Location</li>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not working? Or what? It's unclear for me what's you asking.

Comment: can you not just use `locations_path(82)`?

Comment: This is what I get, http://localhost:3030/locations.82 instead of http://localhost:3030/locations/82

Comment: Sorry, I just figured it out. It had to be singular!.........location_path(82)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<%= link_to location_path(82) do %>
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  <li class="border-top border-bottom">Location</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I figured it out a few minutes ago, you're right, it has to be singular. Thanks!